# How to use onClick in fragment in data binding?

Tags: android, data-binding

I want to use onClick method in fragment but data binding doesn't see method.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FragmentTodayBinding fragmentTodayBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_today, container, false);
    View view = fragmentTodayBinding.getRoot();
    final MainViewModel mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    fragmentTodayBinding.setMainViewModel(mainViewModel);
fragmentTodayBinding.searchButton.setOnClickListener(this::onSearchClick);          
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSearchClick(View v) {
    mainViewModel.getCity();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "X", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Button xml:

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:onClick="@{(v)-> todayFragmentInterface.onSearchClick(v)}"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp" />
```

How to use it properly in fragment?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Follow this step:

1) Add this line in `onCreateView`

```
fragmentTodayBinding.fragment = this;
```

2) Add this line in your `layout.xml`

```
<variable name="fragment" type="yourPackage.ClassName" />
```

3) Edit onClick in xml with

```
android:onClick="@{(v)-> fragment.onSearchClick(v)}"
```

You can also remove:

```
fragmentTodayBinding.searchButton.setOnClickListener(this::onSearchClick);
```

I saw that you use `@Override` so needs an Interface, the goal is the same, just use variable interface in the xml variable (and refer to it with package of interface), than use `fragmentTodayBinding.myInterface = this;`

So:

1) `fragmentTodayBinding.myInterface = this;`

2) `<variable name="myInterface" type="yourPackage.Interface" />`

3) `android:onClick="@{(v)-> myInterface.onSearchClick(v)}"`

Comment: "fragmentTodayBinding.myInterface = this" this is missed in my code where I used 

<variable
        name="handler"
        type="com.manju1375.taskmarker.ui.createtasks.CreateTaskFragment" /> 
with in xml. After adding 

binding.handler = this

Click listener started working.